# Gestures on the newboston

Tags: android, gestures

I want to ask a few questions about this code. I need help, please

**Questions:**

1. Why do they implement the Gesture detector Interface this way **`GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`**
   this is the first time I see Interface like this
2. **`myGesture=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);`**
   why do they initialize an object from the Interface?
   Can't it be done only if we use an anonymous class?
   And why did they use (gesture detector compact) instead of (gesture detector)?
   I can't understand the (this) keyword referring to what.
   Can anyone explain it to me?
   And how to initialize the object without using the (this) keyword?
3. also this line of code **`myGesture.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);`**
   I can't understand the significance of its presence

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

private TextView textView1;
private GestureDetectorCompat myGesture;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    myGesture=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    myGesture.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    return this.myGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText(" onSingleTapConfirmed");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText("onDoubleTap");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText("onDoubleTapEvent");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText("onDown");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    textView1.setText("onShowPress");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText(" onSingleTapUp");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    textView1.setText(" onScroll");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    textView1.setText(" onLongPress");
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    textView1.setText("onFling");
    return true;

}
}
```

I searched about these questions and I didn't find anything useful.
Can anybody explain me?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on those methods? And the class implements those 2 interfaces for the GestureDetector, what's wrong with that? The code is much cleaner with `this` instead of anonymous classes

Comment: which one to read , i don't understand documentations it's confusing

Comment: Look at the classes that are used. Read the method parameters and descriptions. It's only JavaDoc, so if you understand Java, then that's how you learn what methods do what. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html

Answer (score 1):

> GestureDetectorCompat (Context context, 
>                  GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener)

The Activity is a Context and a GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, so that explains `(this, this)`

> void setOnDoubleTapListener (GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener listener)

That interface is also implemented on the Activity, so again `this` is used.

---

> can someone explain and initialize the object without (this) keyword

Sure, you could, but making inner, anonymous class gets all the code nested, and it just looks messy.

> this line of code myGesture.setOnDoubleTapListener(this); cant understand What the significance of its presence

Its significance? It detects a double tap...